# How to encode XML in T SQL without the additional XML overhead

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a database which (For whatever reason) has a column containing pipe delimited data.

I want to parse this data quickly, so I've thought of converting this column (nvarchar) into an XML by replacing the pipes with XML attributes and putting it into an XML data typed column somewhere else.

It works, except in the case where that column had a character that required encoding, such a '<' character.

I found I could encode XML using FOR XML clause, however, that appears to inject some XML tags around the data.

For example: (this gives error on bad character)

```
SELECT CAST('<f>' + replace(value,'|','</f><f>') + '</f>' AS XML)
FROM TABLE
```

this gives xml encoded value, but wraps it in "< value> < /value>" tag

```
  SELECT value
   FROM table
  FOR XML PATH('')
```

Any ideas on how I can get the XML encoded value without this extra tag added,  so I can convert the pipe format to XML after it's done (preferably in one swoop)?

EDIT: since people are asking, this is what 5 potential rows of data might look like

```
foo
foo|bar
foo|bar|1
foo||
baz|
```

And the results would be

```
Col1, Col2, Col3
foo,null,null
foo,bar,null
foo,bar,1
foo,null,null
baz,null,null
```

I'm achieving this by using the resulting XML type in a sub query such as: (it can be up to 4 columns pr 3 pipes in any given row)

```
    SELECT 
          *,
         x.query('f[1]').value('.','nVarChar(2048)')  Col1
        ,x.query('f[2]').value('.','nVarChar(2048)')  Col2
        ,x.query('f[3]').value('.','nvarchar(2048)')  Col3
        ,x.query('f[4]').value('.','nvarchar(2048)')  Col4
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
        CAST('<f>' + REPLACE(Value,'|','</f><f>') + '</f>' AS XML) as x
     FROM  table
    ) y
```

@srutzky makes a great point. No, I do not need to do XML here at all. If I can find a fast & clean way to parse pipes in a set based operation, I'll do that. Will review the SQL# documentation...

Comment: can you show an example of what your data in the pipe delimited column looks like and what you would like output to be?

Comment: Do you *actually* have a performance problem or do you just *think* you have one (premature optimization)? Because building XML like this is not at all advisable, it will needlessly increase the potential of blowing up in edge cases. Use the built-in XML capabilities of SQL Server, they should be plenty fast. The [EXPLICIT Mode of FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx) should give you enough flexibility to output your structure exactly as you want it.

Comment: @Tomalak Why do you suggest Explicit Mode? Better use Path Mode.

Comment: @Shnugo There's nothing wrong with explicit mode, or is there?

Comment: @Tomalak Well, just the absolutely not intuitive handling... Path Mode Let's you build your XML really easy. Even deeper nestings are good to write and even better to read. I'd prefer Path Mode in any case.

Comment: @Shnugo Yeah, it's a matter of preference. I suggested it because the OP  seems to be aware of `PATH` and because it's hard to say from the question what the data looks like and what the output is supposed to look like (this question has a strong whiff of XY-problem.)

Comment: Why you are converting pipe-delimited into XML instead of simply splitting the delimited data? A SQLCLR UDF, or even a properly done T-SQL splitter (one that uses an inline numbers table), used via `CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitterFunction(otherTable.DelimitedDataColumn)`. A SQLCLR splitter is much more scalable than the XML method (which is still better than the recursive CTE and WHILE loop methods) and won't break on the special XML characters. Check out the Free version of [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) (which I wrote, but is free) and the **String_Split** and **String_Split4k** functions.

Comment: @KamranFarzami I've added some examples

Comment: @Shnugo thank you, you are right. I'm sorry about that. I've gone back and marked each answer

Comment: @srutzky, I was only doing it this way as I thought XML parses in SQL was native and fast. I couldn't get a set based parser working, and wasn't sure if CLR would actually be faster.. I will look at your link.. thanks

Comment: @srutzky your string_split with cross apply works great, but problem is it's giving me N records back with duplicate data and a new SplitNum. I need extra columns, not extra records (sorry, i've updated my question to specify this). Is there an efficient way to use your method to generate columns? seems like PIVOT would be expensive here...

Comment: @user3688611, Hi, great that you went back to mark old answers. Sure the Users will be happy with the reputation points they get from there. Please allow me one more hint: There are two separate actions possible: voting and accepting. If one of the answers *solves* your issue you should tick the acceptance check below the vote counter. This will mark the question as resolved and will provide additional rep points to the answerer. Thx and happy coding!

Comment: @user3688611, back to your question: Your example data does not contain any "bad" character... Did you try my approach below? This will first convert your string to XML (and escape all special characters automatically!) and then split it. As result you get your table without the need to pivot... (example in the middle of my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST('<values><f>' + 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(value,'&','&amp;')
                    ,'"','&quot;')
                ,'<','&lt;')
            ,'>','&gt;')
        ,'|','</f><f>') + '</f></values>' AS XML)
FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following BUT you need to make sure the content is "xml safe", in other words the content does not contain values which xml will reject (look into xml element content parsing).
Try the following...it's test script to see if it does what you want..

```
UPDATE:
```

ok, it might help if I read the question all the way through...2 steps...split the pipes and then xml all the split items...try this:

Create the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_SPLIT]
(
  @s nvarchar(max),
  @trimPieces bit,
  @returnEmptyStrings bit,
  @delimiter nvarchar(10)
)
RETURNS @t TABLE (val nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int, @j int

    SELECT @i = 0, @j = (LEN(@s) - LEN(REPLACE(@s,@delimiter,'')))

    ;WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT i = @i + 1,
            s = @s,
            n = substring(@s, 0, charindex(@delimiter, @s)),
            m = substring(@s, charindex(@delimiter, @s)+1, len(@s) - charindex(@delimiter, @s))
            UNION ALL
        SELECT i = cte.i + 1,
            s = cte.m, 
            n = substring(cte.m, 0, charindex(@delimiter, cte.m)),
            m = substring(cte.m, charindex(@delimiter, cte.m) + 1, len(cte.m)-charindex(@delimiter, cte.m))
        FROM cte
        WHERE i <= @j
    )
    INSERT INTO @t (val)
        SELECT [pieces]
        FROM (
            SELECT CASE 
                WHEN @trimPieces = 1 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CASE WHEN i <= @j THEN n ELSE m END))
                ELSE CASE WHEN i <= @j THEN n ELSE m END
                END AS [pieces]
            FROM cte
            ) t
        WHERE (@returnEmptyStrings = 0 AND LEN(pieces) > 0)
        OR (@returnEmptyStrings = 1)
        OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

RETURN

END
```

next try the following to test...

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(500) = 'test|<html>this</html>|boogie woogie| SDGDSFG| game<br /> on |working| this|'

SELECT REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE([val],'&','&amp;')
                ,'"','&quot;')
            ,'<','&lt;')
        ,'>','&gt;')
     AS [f]
FROM [dbo].[udf_SPLIT](@str,1,0,'|')
FOR XML PATH('')
```

If not totally correct, hopefully will put you on right path...

HTH

Dave

Comment: Bruce's answer above should deal with the "xml Safe" issue...I updated my answer to combine with his...

Comment: thank you for the thorough reply! I think I might have worded my question poorly.. I actually was only using XML so that I could parse out the pipes in a set based operation.. Not because I needed to "XMLIFY" the data. The XML type was just a hack to do set based parsing as I couldn't get it to work with a function. I've updated my question above

Comment: it seems like I could use your function here with a cross apply, but would need to pivot to get to column data. I'll play with to see if I can avoid XML stuff altogether

Answer (score 1):

Your idea was absolutely OK: By making an XML out of your string the XML engine will convert all special characters properly. After your splitting the XML should be correct.

If your string is stored in a column you can avoid the  automatically given name by either doing kind of *computation* (something like `'' + YourColumn`) or you give the column an alias `AS [*]`:

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)='300|2€&ÄÖÜ|This is text -> should be text|2015-12-31';

SELECT @str FOR XML PATH('');
/*
300|2€&amp;ÄÖÜ|This is text -&gt; should be text|2015-12-31
*/

DECLARE @Xml XML=(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @str FOR XML PATH('')),'|','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML));

SELECT @Xml.value('/x[1]','int') AS IntTypeSave
      ,@Xml.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)') AS VarcharTypeSave
      ,@Xml.value('/x[4]','datetime') AS DateTypeSave;

/*
300           This is text -> should be text          2015-12-31 00:00:00.000
*/

SELECT X.value('.','varchar(max)') AS EachX
FROM @Xml.nodes('/x') AS Each(X);

/*
300
2€&ÄÖÜ
This is text -> should be text
2015-12-31
*/
```